# Microsoft Data Mining add-in for office

Tags: add-in, data-mining

If i have installed SQL Server 2008 and Office 2010, which data mining add-in should i choose? I found

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Data Mining Add-ins for Microsoft Office 2007

and

Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Data Mining Add-ins for Microsoft® Office® 2010

Comment: I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Data Mining Add-ins for Microsoft Office 2007. This works, but sometimes excel shows dialog with warning about this add-in and disable it.

Answer (score 2):

The Office 2010 add-in should work with 2008.  I installed it with 2008 and did not run into any problems.  However, I strongly recommend upgrading your SQL Server to 2012 since there are additional business intelligence benefits with 2012.